# Nginx deployed in docker container doesn't expose nuxtjs deployed in another docker container (502 Bad Gateway)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nuxt.js

I'm trying to run nuxtjs application using nginx as proxy server in docker containers. So, I have 2 containers: nginx and nuxt
[image]

here is how I'm building nuxt application

```
FROM node:11.15
ENV APP_ROOT /src
RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
ENV host 0.0.0.0
```

The result seems to be fine
[image]

Next is nginx config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.iceik.com.ua;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://nuxt:3000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Also I've tried this nginx config

```
upstream nuxt {
  server nuxt:3000;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.iceik.com.ua;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://nuxt;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

And finally my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
  nuxt:
    build: ./app/
    container_name: nuxt
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command:
      "npm run start"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nuxt
```

I can ping nuxt container from nginx container
[image]

Also here are opened ports
[image]

So, the expected result is that I can access my nuxt application.
However I'm getting 502 Bad Gateway

Do you have any ideas why nginx doesn't expose my nuxt application?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: please post nginx error logs while accessing `dev.iceik.com.ua`

Comment: try to `curl -k -v http://nuxt:3000` for checking port 3000 is open

Comment: Hello @ThanhNguyenVan 
I've updated first post where added screenshot with opened ports.

However curl -k -v http://nuxt:3000 retrieves 
* Rebuilt URL to: http://nuxt:3000/
* Could not resolve host: nuxt
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nuxt

Do you understand why?

Comment: access to `nginx` container then take a `curl`

Comment: can you access `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan
Aw sorry I executed this command not inside the container.. So, when I'm executing curl -k -v http://nuxt:3000 inside nginx container I'm getting
* Rebuilt URL to: http://nuxt:3000/
*   Trying 172.19.0.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.19.0.2 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to nuxt port 3000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to nuxt port 3000: Connection refused

Do you know possible causes of connection refused in my case?

Comment: Check your node.js is expose port 3000 to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan you are damn right! Node js exposed localhost:3000 instead of 0.0.0.0:3000. Now I changed it to 0.0.0.0:3000 and it works! Thanks a lot for your ideas! If you will create new answer I will mark it as correct and give you upvote (not sure if I can)

Comment: i have added the answer, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs is exposed `localhost:3000` instead of `0.0.0.0:3000`

Please correct it. It will work

Answer (score 0):

Always good that your containers put into a network if they need to talk each other, other way is to use Host network(only works in linux). Try below `docker-compose.yml` they should be able to talk each other from the container names.

```
version: "3"

services:
  nuxt:
    build: ./app/
    container_name: nuxt
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command:
      "npm run start"
    networks:
      - my_net

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nuxt
    networks:
      - my_net

networks:
  my_net:
    driver: "bridge"
```

Comment: I modified docker-compose as you suggested but, it didn't help. Also I found in documentation that
By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.